# Cannot invoke "PacienteService.findById(java.lang.Integer)" because "this.service" is null

Tags: java, spring-boot, testes

Estou fazendo testes numa RestAPI em Java e não estou conseguindo mockar a minha classe Service

sempre aparece esse erro: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.tcc.tccbackend.services.PacienteService.findById(java.lang.Integer)" because "this.service" is null`.

Código:

```
@Mock
    private PacienteService service;

@Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

@BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        RestAssuredMockMvc.mockMvc(mockMvc);
    }

@Test
    @DisplayName("Retorna sucesso quando busca um paciente ")
    public void t4() {
        Mockito.when(service.findById(9999))
                .thenReturn(new Paciente(9999, "Gilberson", "gilber@gmail.com", "68211836104", "(67) 99625-5371", new Date(), List.of()));
        RestAssuredMockMvc
                .given()
                .header("Authorization", getJWT())
                .accept(ContentType.JSON)
                .when()
                .get("/pacientes/9999")
                .then().statusCode(200);
    }
```

Versões:

- Java 17
- RestAssured 5.3.0
- SpringBoot 2.7.0
- SpringBoot Starter Test 2.7.0

Answer (score 0):

PacienteService é uma classe? Se sim, tente instanciar a variável service, de acordo com o construtor da classe:

```
private PacienteService service = new PacienteService();
```

Essa exception está ocorrendo porque não tem nenhum valor atribuído à service, então a variável está guardando um valor null.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).